# What is this VHDL code setting max and min to? An explanation of fixed point representation would be helpful

Tags: vhdl

```
 constant MAX      : unsigned(18 downto 0) := "100" & x"0000";
 constant MIN      : unsigned(18 downto 0) := "001" & x"0000";
```

What is this VHDL code setting max and min to? An explanation of fixed point representation would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The `&` operator concatenates the two bit vectors `"100"` and `x"0000"` (e.g. `"00" & "11"` would be equivalent to `"0011"`).
- The `X"012345689ABCDEF"` syntax means that the following vector should be interpreted as a hex number (e.g. `X"0"` actually is `"0000"`, `X"F"` would be `"1111"` or `X"0F"` would be `"00001111"`). This allows you to write a bit vector in a more compact way.

For the interpretation of a bit vector check e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system

For representation of hexdecimal numbers check e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

---

Edit for clarification: I assume you are using the `unsigned` type from the `numeric_std` package. From the header of that package

```
This package defines numeric types and arithmetic functions
for use with synthesis tools. Two numeric types are defined:
-- > UNSIGNED: represents UNSIGNED number in vector form
-- > SIGNED: represents a SIGNED number in vector form
The base element type is type STD_LOGIC.
The leftmost bit is treated as the most significant bit.
Signed vectors are represented in two's complement form.
```

So your `MAX` is set to 2^18 and your `MIN` to 2^16.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the syntax of VHDL and the use of binary/hex. What I don't understand is how this specific code does fixed point representation of a decimal number and what it is setting max and min to.

Comment: Edited my answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If the code is doing a fixed-point representation of some fractional decimal number, you did not provide enough context to interpret the values.